# Clarifications needed for a question concerning ${\rm Aut}(\mathbb{Z}_{2}\times \mathbb{Z}_{2})\cong S_{3}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, symmetric-groups, automorphism-group

[image]

I am trying to show ${\rm Aut}(\mathbb{Z}_{2}\times \mathbb{Z}_{2})\cong S_{3}$.  So in the included image, example 8, it asks the reader to find all the automorphism group in the set $\mathbb{Z}_{2}\times \mathbb{Z}_{2}$.  The solution states:

> Every automorphism of $\mathbb{Z}_{2}\times \mathbb{Z}_{2}$ must leave the identity $(0,0)$ fixed.  However, the three other elements are algebraically identical--for instance, they are each of order 2 and commute with the other elements.  So any of the six permutations of them gives an automorphism.  Thus ${\rm Aut}(\mathbb{Z}_{2}\times \mathbb{Z}_{2})\cong D_{3}$.  We can also represent these automorphism as $2 \times 2$ matrices from the ring of matrices $M_{2}(\mathbb{Z}_{2})$, mapping the four vectors [0 0], [1 0], [0 1], [1 1] to themselves.

I am confused about what the sentence "we can also represent these automorphism as $2 \times 2$ matrices from the ring of matrices $M_{2}(\mathbb{Z}_{2})$, mapping the four vectors [0 0], [1 0], [0 1], [1 1] to themselves." means.  I mean is it saying that the reader can create some sort of isomorphic linear transformations sending each one of those four vectors to a two by two matrix with a determinant equal to one?  Or does it mean something else.  I am also not clear in how to transcribe that sentence into mathematical notation.  Thank you in advance.

Comment: Please don't rely on pictures of text.

Comment: @Shaun I don't understand your advice, should I typed out the solution instead?  Is the resolution of the text not clear, or did I do something else that have breached some sort of etiquette about posting on MSE?

Comment: Pictures of text aren't user friendly. They cannot be searched and, on some devices, they do not render.

Comment: Please type up the text.

Comment: @SethMai: Images are not searchable, so this is not good.

Comment: @Shaun okay, okay, I will type out the solution also too.

Comment: Thank you, @SethMai.

Comment: $SL(2,2)$ has $6$ elements and non-Abelian. There is only one such group, $S_3$.

Comment: @Shaun I just edit my post and typed up the solution.  :)

Comment: @markvs I just don't know what the sentence is saying when it says i can send a column vector to themselves to create a 2 by 2 matrix.  Actually, I am not sure if it is saying that I should send two column vectors to themselves or one column vector to themselves to create a 2 by 2 matrix.

Comment: $2\times 2$ matrices have two.columns.Since you do not want det$=0$, there are exactly 3 options for the first column. For each first column there are two optiond for the second column. Hence 6 choices altogether. The phrase is about the  lin  transf asociated with the matrix. It sends vectors (points) to vectors (points). The transformation is determined by the images of basic vectors. The first column is the image of the first vector, the second colimn is the image of the second vector.

Answer (score 2):

Every automorphism of $G:=(\Bbb{Z}/2\Bbb{Z})\times(\Bbb{Z}/2\Bbb{Z})$ is a bijection from $G$ to itself. Moreover any automorphism maps $(0,0)$ to $(0,0)$. From here it is not difficult to check that any such automorphism is in fact an $\Bbb{F}_2$-linear map, where $\Bbb{F}_2=\Bbb{Z}/2\Bbb{Z}$ is the field of two elements.

Every $\Bbb{F}_2$-linear map from $G=\Bbb{F}_2^2$ to itself can be represented by a $2\times2$-matrix with coefficients in $\Bbb{F}_2$. This is what the quoted sentence intends to convey; that there exists a map
$$\operatorname{Aut}(G)\ \longrightarrow\ \operatorname{GL}_2(\Bbb{F}_2),$$
that maps automorphisms of $G$ to (invertible) $2\times2$-matrices over $\Bbb{F}_2$. Such a map is in fact an isomorphism, but the text you quote does not make a convincing argument that this is so, in my humble opinion.

Comment: do I usually need to write out an explicit map that maps $Aut(G) \rightarrow GL_{2}(\mathbb{F}_{2})$?  If so, what would that look like?

Comment: @SethMai It depends. You could argue that any choice of basis for $\Bbb{F}_2^2$ yields such a map that is injective. Conversely, you could show that every invertible matrix in $\Bbb{GL}_2(\Bbb{F}_2)$ defines a distinct group automorphism of $G$. Then you have injections going both ways, and hence there is a bijection. But if you don't know anything about $\operatorname{GL}_2(\Bbb{F}_2)$ yet, then this certainly isn't the easiest way to go at all.

Comment: @SethMai Assuming less prior knowledge, it makes more sense to argue directly that every automorphism of $G$ defines a permutation of the three nonzero vectors. So $\operatorname{Aut}(G)$ is (isomorphic to) a subgroup of $S_3$. Then it remains to show that *every* permutation defines an automorphism. This is a matter of bookkeeping; a bit cumbersome but not difficult at all.

Comment: I already construct a cayley table for both $S_3$ and the group of 2 by 2 matrices with determinant equal to one.  I know i can just do entry matching for both tables to show isomorphism.  But I would not know how to write out an explicit map that is talked about in the exampled solution.  Either I forgot my linear algebra, or I just don't know how to map one two by one column vector to two two by two column vectors and turn that into a matrix.

Comment: @SethMai Just choose a numbering of the nonzero elements in $G$, say $1\ \mapsto\ (1,0)$, $2\ \mapsto\ (0,1)$ and $3\ \mapsto\ (1,1)$. Then each matrix permutes these three vectors, and so gives an element of $S_3$.

Comment: ok ok, I see what you mean.  Thank you so much for your suggestions and help.  Very much appreciated it.  :)

Comment: @SethMai Conversely, again numbering the nonzero elements of $G$, any permutation in $S_3$ maps any basis of $\Bbb{F}_2^2$ to another basis; these are the columns of the corresponding matrix.